# what is the url for express checkout

Tags: php, paypal, express-checkout, 2checkout

I follow this example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/UhNka4VaaRRGY1TK32LE?p=preview

I copy the code and modify it. My question is what is the link that I muse use to pay with paypal sandbox.

```
 url: "http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?sandbox=1&direct=1&returnurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/return.htm&cancelurl=http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/cancel.htm"
```

In this example he uses `http://166.78.8.98/cgi-bin/aries.cgi?` I must use another link because it's not correct. Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [button generator provided by paypal](http://paypal.github.io/JavaScriptButtons/). There you can customize the button you want, the page also describes how to implement it in your website.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, the *extensive* documentation Paypal provides doesn't make it easy to answer that (simple) question :)

Best I could find from the **Support** site (alas, not the developer site) for *base* urls:

https://ppmts.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/391

- that document also provides links to list of API urls (which you will also need).

Hth.